# While trying to retrieve currentLocation, i get the error 'Cannot read property 'getCurrentPosition' of undefined'

Tags: react-native, react-redux

I am trying to create a React Native App thats trying to fetch the current location using the navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition function and i encounter the error 'Cannot read property 'getCurrentPosition' of undefined'

The following is the code that i use:

```
import update from "react-addons-update";
import constants from "./actionConstants";


//----------------------
//Constants
//----------------------

const { GET_CURRENT_LOCATION } = constants;

//----------------------
// Actions
//----------------------

export function getCurrentLocation(){
    return(dispatch)=>{
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
            (position)=>{
                dispatch({
                    type:GET_CURRENT_LOCATION,
                    payload:position
                });
            },
            (error)=> console.log(error.message),
            {enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 20000, maximumAge:1000}
        );
    }
}

//----------------------
// Action Handlers
//----------------------

function handleGetCurrentLocation(state, action){
    return update(state,{
        region:{
            $set:action.payload
        }
    })
}

const ACTION_HANDLERS = {
    GET_CURRENT_LOCATION:handleGetCurrentLocation
}
const initialState = {
    region: {}
};

export function HomeReducer(state = initialState, action){
    const handler = ACTION_HANDLERS[action.type];
    return handler ? handler(state, action) : state;    
}
```

My actionConstants.js file is:

```
export default {
    GET_CURRENT_LOCATION:"GET_CURRENT_LOCATION"
};
```

This is being called in the following file :

```
import React from "react";
import {View, Text} from "react-native";
import MapContainer from "./MapContainer";
import {Container} from "native-base";

export default class Home extends React.Component{

    componentDidMount(){
        this.props.getCurrentLocation();
    }

    render(){
        const region = {
            latitude : 3.146642,
            longitude : 101.695845,
            latitudeDelta:0.0922,
            longitudeDelta:0.0421 
        }
        return(
            <Container>
                <MapContainer region={region}/>
            </Container>
        );

    }
}
```

Could someone help.. Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Seems that you are using the wrong library to get the geolocation, you should use https://github.com/Agontuk/react-native-geolocation-service instead.

Comment: @SteveAlves: thanks a lot!!!! This worked for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what is navigator ? 
here is my working code

```
import Geolocation from 'react-native-geolocation-service';

 componentWillMount() {
    Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
              (position) => {
                addLocation(position.coords);
              },
              (error) => {
                console.error(error);
              },
              { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 15000, maximumAge: 10000 },
            );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

where have you called getCurrentLocation? it seems you have not called it.

For me, this code works without importing any extra library:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {ToastAndroid } from 'react-native';

export default class location extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
    };
  }
 getCurrentLocation(){
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
        ToastAndroid.show((position.coords.latitude + ', ' + position.coords.longitude),ToastAndroid.LONG);
    }, function (e) {
        ToastAndroid.show(e, ToastAndroid.SHORT)
    }, {enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 20000, maximumAge:1000});
 }
  render() {
    return (
      <View>{this.getCurrentLocation()}</View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: my requirement is that the position returned should be updated in the redux store through dispatch. I have added the Component that calls this function in the code above